# import content from csv to mysql database

Tags: php

There is a mysql database named: `example` which has a table named: `products` it have fields: `products_model` and `products_image`. the model field is unique.

now i have a csv file named `data.csv`. which have two column products_model and `products_image`.i use the following code. but it doesn't import the data into the database.what's wrong with my code?

```
    $fp = fopen("data.csv","r");
$length = 4096; //have to be optional length
$fildDelineate = ',' ;//or "|" declare what you need
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="zencartone";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$link  = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$databasetable  = 'products';

$counter = 1;//to omission first row if it is table headers

while($line = fgetcsv($fp,$length,$fildDelineate)){
    foreach($line as $key=>$value){
        //for example insert in 3 column
        $importSQL = "insert into $databasetable  (products_model, products_image) values('$line[0]','$line[1]')";
        mysql_query($importSQL) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $counter++;
}
fclose($fp);
```

data.csv:

have two column:

```
products_model  products_image
MG200MMS    dress/201247561673.jpg
MG400-32MB  dress/2012471141673.jpg
MSIMPRO dress/201247741673.jpg
DVD-RPMK    dress/2012471831673.jpg
DVD-BLDRNDC dress/2012474221673.jpg
DVD-MATR    dress/201112132056773.jpg
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is going wrong?

Comment: When you keep updating your question, changing code per answers, it's very difficult to answer.  I would strongly suggest you keep the question as it was in the beginning.  You current code is way off what it was when the question was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

Use the following loop:

```
while($line = fgets($fp)) {
    $lineArray = explode("\t", $line); // Use tab as delimiter.
    $importSQL = "insert into $databasetable  (products_model, products_image) values ('".$lineArray[0]."','".$lineArray[1]."')";
    mysql_query($importSQL) or die(mysql_error());
    $counter++;
}
```

SQL errors:

```
$importSQL = "insert into $databasetable values('$line[0]','$line[1]')";
```

You need to specify the column names:

```
$importSQL = "insert into $databasetable (col1, col2) values('$line[0]','$line[1]')";
```

Edit: `fgetcsv($fp,$length,$fildDelineate,'')`

Enclosure param is set to empty string. You can get rid of it if you have no enclosures around the values in the CSV:

```
fgetcsv($fp,$length,$fildDelineate)
```

Otherwise, set the correct enclosure (double quotes or single quote).

Comment: Stegrex,if i want to update some data in the table with csv column data, how do i do? thank you

Comment: Where the $importSQL string is, you can use the SQL query "update products set products_image = '".$lineArray[1]."' where products_model = '". $lineArray[0]."'";

Answer (score 3):

You problem is in the loop:

```
while(!fopen($fp)){
    if(!$line = fgetcsv($fp,$length,$fildDelineate,'')&& $counter){
        continue;
    }
    foreach($line as $key=>$value){
```

is incorrect.  Your file is already open (in the first line of code).  In the loop you need to read, not re-open.  Your loop should be like this:

```
while($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")){
    foreach($line as $key=>$value){
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As your file seems to TSV (tab-separated-values), I updated the code above to use the tab char as the separator when reading data.

Comment: i am sorry , it shows Warning: fgetcsv() [function.fgetcsv]: enclosure must be a character

Comment: @down1234 I just copied your code from the next line.  I've updated my answer now.

Comment: i am sorry. when i run the code, it's all ok now, but the database can't have the csv data. why? thank you

Comment: What do you mean "can't have the csv data"? What happens?  What do you get?

Comment: when i run the code, it shows me a blank page. then i looked for the database, there is no data in the table.

Comment: @down1234 Your file is actually not CSV. It looks more like a TSV since it doesn't appear to be comma delimited.

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Put this in the beginning of your php code: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` - and see if you get anything

Comment: @down1234 As Stegrex noted, you seem to have `\t` as your field separator instead of a comma.  I updated my answer to take that into account

Comment: i add the code, after run the page, it still return me a blank page. the data still haven't been inserted into the table.

Comment: Aleks G, if i want to update some data in the table with csv column data, how do i do? thank you

Comment: @Down1234 you already have the rest of the code.  Assuming you fix the errors as indicated in my answer the one from Stegrex, everything should work.